# tabbarcontroller + navigation. How to make so that landscape one representation had an orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I created application in which has:

- `viewcontroller`,
- `navigationviewcontroller`,
- `tabbarviewcontroller`.

I have many tabs and respectively many representations. The problem is that when I click one tab there should be only Portrait orientation. But when I click the following tab I should have a representation with all types of orientation.

Precisely to understand what I want, start the skype application on iPhone. The first tab can't pass into Landscape, the second too can't transfer. But if opening a chat it should be possible to transfer to any mode of orientation.

I tried to add the following code, but it works in `navigationcontroller` not in `tabcontroller`.

`tabcontroller`:

```
int test = 0;
    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()  
        {
                int i = 0;
            foreach (var v in ViewControllers) {
                if (v.GetType () == typeof(CreateCompViewController)) {
                    test = i;
                    break;
                }i++;
            }
            int s = test;
            test++;
            if (test==i)
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;

            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }
```

Thus if I make compulsorily without condition, everything works. Help to understand.

I program on monotouch, but it without difference. All functions are identical. If you can give an example on xcode. It makes no difference to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

The above methods don't get called of a viewcontroller if they are inside any tabbarcontroller of navigationcontroller. If these methods are declared inside tabbarcontroller or navigation controller then they will get called. In my case the viewcontrollers was inside navigationcontroller and the navigation controllers are inside a tabbarcontroller.

For solving this I make a class FixedOrientationTab, it is a subclass of UITabBarController, and a navigation class OrientationEnabledNavigation, it is a subclass of UINavigationController. Then I implemented `shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods inside FixedOrientationTab and OrientationEnabledNavigation.

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation : UINavigationController

@end
```

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.m**

```
#import "OrientationEnabledNavigation.h"

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation ()

@end

@implementation OrientationEnabledNavigation

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
//    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**FixedOrientationTab.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FixedOrientationTab : UITabBarController

@end
```

**FixedOrientationTab.m**

```
#import "FixedOrientationTab.h"

@interface FixedOrientationTab ()

@end

@implementation FixedOrientationTab

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    //    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Then if you want to use navigation controller in your project then use OrientationEnabledNavigation and for tabbar FixedOrientationTab. After that if you implement `shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` these method inside your viewcontroller then they will get called.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response, you couldn't attach the source code. It is simple to me to understand with some difficulty a code from the first, I program under mono. Thanks!

Comment: I've discussed what I've done to solve the problem. I've used mono once but that was for android. So I could not give you mono code example. But try to get the idea.